# Add timestamp in a different sheet when cell equals a specific value with matching ID #'s

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am using google sheets and have one sheet called Sales that stores my data for the month's sales and another sheet that pulls in inventory data with index(match) all based on the Item#. I want to mark a sold product sold with "yes" colum L. Once I select YES i would like the script to enter the sold date into the inventory sheet for the item that was sold. I feel like I am so close but I only have the timestamp going to the adjacent cell and I need it to look up the ID number and leave the timestamp in the inventory sheet for the product that sold. Note: make a copy of the sales sheet every month rename it "Sales for XXX" and then wipe the data clean in the "Sales" sheet so I need the timestamp to stick and not be removed after the data is cleared for the next month.

```
function onEdit(event){ 
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "SALES" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
  var ColL = 12;  // Column Number of "L"
  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColL) {
    // An edit has occurred in Column L
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = 
event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColL+1);
    var timestamp = new Date(); // Get the current time
    // We'll do something different, depending on the selected value
    switch (state) {
      case "Yes":
        // Write timestamp into adjacent cell
        adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
        break;
      case "No":
        // Erase timestamp in adjacent cell
        adjacent.clearContent();
        break;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the requirements of your note at the end, but it does look like you are close. To find and manipulate values in a sheet in Apps Script, you can use the range getValues() and setValues() methods to work with sheet data as a two-dimensional array. For example, below is a function that takes a timestamp and ID as arguments, and finds the corresponding row in a sheet named "INVENTORY" with ID in the first column, and writes the timestamp to the second column. You'll need to tweak it for your sheet layout, but this should help you get going in the right direction.

This function rewrites the INVENTORY sheet every time it runs. If that's overkill, you could use an array.forEach function to find the row with the ID that matches. The second argument in a forEach callback is the index of the element being evaluated, which could be used to return the row number of the matched row.

```
/*
  Assumes a sheet named INVENTORY with IDs in the first column and timestamps in 
  the second column, with column headers. The column headers help ensure that the 
  getValues and setValues arrays have the same dimensions.
*/
function setSoldTimestamp(timestamp,id){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('INVENTORY'); // change to your inventory sheet name
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var arSheet = range.getValues();
  // there are a lot of different ways you could iterate through
  // the array to find what you are looking for. I like map and filter.
  var arOut = arSheet.map(function(row){
    if (row[0] == id) { // change index to match your ID column number - 1
      row[1] = timestamp; // change index to match your timestamp column number - 1
      return row
    } else {
      return row
    }
  });
  range.setValues(arOut);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an easy way to do this with just formulas. 
With an if statement. I am not pulling numbers from a separate sheet because I am not sure how you are implementing that.

[At any rate here is a demo on a single sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13gOpgb16c2weuYaLkZug5tqkA6DwjItn6O3xvKN2CHI/edit?usp=sharing)

And here is the code I used.

```
function onEdit(event){ 
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "SALES" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var currCell = s.getActiveCell()
    var ajCell = s.getRange(currCell.getRow(), currCell.getColumn()+1)
    if(currCell.getValue() === "YES"){
      ajCell.setValue(new Date())
    }else{
     ajCell.setValue("")
    }                         
  }
}
```